# Unity Android UI Buttons to Replace WASD Controls For Snake

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to programing and that all stuff. I watched on youtube how to create snake game and I want to add a script for my buttons to move the player. I created [ui buttons like this](https://ibb.co/fzChcU) but when I click them nothing happens, of course. I added simple assets for cross-platform and all that's done but I don't know how to script it. I can move the snake with my `W A S D` keys but I wanna move with the UI buttons. Here's my script:

```
 private void Update()
    {

        if (isGameOver)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                onStart.Invoke();
            }
            return;
        }
        GetInput();

        if (isFirstInput)
        {
            SetPlayerDirection();

            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            if (timer > moveRate)
            {
                timer = 0;
                curDirection = targetDirection;
                MovePlayer();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (up || down || left || right)
            {

                isFirstInput = true;
                firstInput.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }

    void GetInput()
    {
        up = Input.GetButtonDown("Up");
        down = Input.GetButtonDown("Down");
        left = Input.GetButtonDown("Left");
        right = Input.GetButtonDown("Right");
    }

    void SetPlayerDirection()
    {
        if (up)
        {
            SetDirection(Direction.up);
        }
        else if (down)
        {
            SetDirection(Direction.down);
        }
        else if (left)
        {
            SetDirection(Direction.left);
        }
        else if (right)
        {
            SetDirection(Direction.right);
        }
    }

    void SetDirection(Direction d)
    {
        if (!isOpposite(d))
        {
            targetDirection = d;
        }
    }

    void MovePlayer()
    {

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        switch (curDirection)
        {

            case Direction.up:
                y = 1;
                break;
            case Direction.down:
                y = -1;
                break;
            case Direction.left:
                x = -1;
                break;
            case Direction.right:
                x = 1;
                break;

        }

        Node targetNode = GetNode(playerNode.x + x, playerNode.y + y);
        if (targetNode == null)
        {
            //Game Over
            onGameOver.Invoke();
        }
        else
        {
            if (isTailNode(targetNode))
            {
                //GameOver
                onGameOver.Invoke();
            }
            else
            {



                bool isScore = false;

                if (targetNode == appleNode)
                {
                    isScore = true;
                }

                Node previousNode = playerNode;
                availbableNodes.Add(previousNode);


                if (isScore)
                {
                    tail.Add(CreateTailNode(previousNode.x, previousNode.y ,tailParent));
                    availbableNodes.Remove(previousNode);
                }

                MoveTail();
                PlacePlayerObject(playerObj, targetNode.worldPosition);
                playerNode = targetNode;
                availbableNodes.Remove(playerNode);

                if (isScore)
                {

                    currentScore++;
                    if(currentScore >= highScore)
                    {
                        highScore = currentScore;
                    }

                    onScore.Invoke();

                    if (availbableNodes.Count > 0)
                    {
                        RandomlyPlaceApple();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //you won
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be fairly simple. You could create methods to handle the events. For instance, lets say you want to bind `SetDirection(Direction.up);` to the "*Up Button"*, you can create a method for that purpose.

```
public void UpDirection(){
SetDirection(Direction.up);
}
```

Go back to the Editor, click on the Up Button, add an `OnClick` event by clicking the + sign. Drag in your script to the empty slot then you should select the relevant function from the DropDown. I hope you get this?

Answer (score 1):

For starters, [Unity has a great ~13 minute video on using UI Buttons](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-button).  Once you watch this video, you'll understand how to connect a UI button to an event (watch at 8:25 if you feel like skipping over the visual details of how buttons work). Next, you'll want to add four functions to your script for your four directional buttons like so:

```
public void UpButtonPressed()
{
    SetDirection(Direction.up);
}
public void DownButtonPressed()
{
    SetDirection(Direction.down);
}
public void LeftButtonPressed()
{
    SetDirection(Direction.left);
}
public void RightButtonPressed()
{
    SetDirection(Direction.right);
}
```

Then just attach them to the correct button's `OnClick` events in the inspector (described in that video at 8:25).